# Update function works directly in SQL but not via javascript?

Tags: php, ajax

Ive tripled checked this like 50 times. The query with the same parameters works directly in sql. I don't even get an error. Ill post below the php function and where i call it. My query to get the row of data to fill the form inputs works fine, ive double checked the name of the action, name of the variables, im going mad.

PHP function

```
function editReservation($connection, $reservation){
    $result = NULL;

    $query = "UPDATE bookings
              SET reservation_type=?, reservation_date=?, 
                    reservation_time=?, special_requirements=?, 
                    party_size=?
              WHERE reservation_code=?";
    if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
                         $data['reservation_type'], $data['reservation_date'],
                         $data['reservation_time'], $data['special_requirements'],
                         $data['party_size'], $data['reservation_code']);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = TRUE;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

AJAX Handler

```
elseif($_POST['action'] == 'editBookingByCode'){
    $data = array(
          "reservation_type" => $_POST['reservation_type'],
          "reservation_date" => $_POST['reservation_date'],
          "reservation_time" => $_POST['reservation_time'],
          "special_requirements" => $_POST['special_requirements'],
          "party_size" => $_POST['party_size'],
          "reservation_code" => $_POST['code'],
        );
    $updated = editReservation($connection, $data);
    echo $updated;
    exit();
}
```

AJAX

```
$("#editBooking").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var number = $('#number').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var time = $('#time').val();
    var size = $('#size').val();
    var occasion = $('#occasion').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    let bookingData = {
            action: "editBookingByCode",
            code: "<?=$booking['reservation_code']?>",
            reservation_type: occasion,
            reservation_date: date,
            reservation_time: time,
            special_requirements: comment,
            party_size: size
        };

    console.log(bookingData);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
            data: bookingData
    })
    .done((result)=>{
        if(result.message == "Success"){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            alert('An error occured, failed to edit booking option, please try again');
        }
```

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, are there any errors at all on the development console?  On the network tab in those tools, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  What is the result of `$stmt->execute()`?

Comment: @David The only error I get in my console is the "An error ocurred..." , ajax returns a status of 200 with a response of 1?, not sure how to check the result of `$stmt->execute()`

Comment: Do you mean you see your `alert()` message?  It's starting to sound like the operation is successful and you're just falsely reporting an error.  What is the value of `result.message` in your AJAX response handler?

Comment: That's what i thought too but the update doesnt take effect in the table. When i attempt to console log the result or result.message it is undefined

Comment: what is the value of `$updated` that you echo in the PHP ajax handler? It looks like you return either `null` or `true` - so where does `result.message` come from?

Comment: What does [errorInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) return? I find it odd that you're binding party_size as a string. Are you sure that's correct? I would expect that to be an integer type.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I commented out the if statement and just told it to `console.log(result)` and it returns 1

Comment: `1` equates to `true` which suggests that `editReservation` succeeds yet you say the update does not commit to db?!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Nope it doesnt kms haha

Comment: @TiernO: What are the exact values being posted to the server?  If you output your `$data` array for debugging, what does it contain?  It really sounds like the query itself is executing successfully, it just might not be doing what you think.

Comment: @David Bro I'm not being funny but if I echo $data how do i find it in the console?

Comment: @TiernO: Anything that's output from the server-side code should be observable in the response to the AJAX request.  Take a look at the network tab of the browser's debugging tools.  In that same tab you can also observe many details about the requests/responses, including the exact values being sent to the server.

Comment: @TiernO - look in the network ytab at the AJAX request - there will be an error but just analyse the data you see. You can use `exit(print_r( $_POST ));` before any other code

Comment: Here is what it outputs Array
(
    [reservation_type] => 4
    [reservation_date] => 2020-07-13
    [reservation_time] => 6
    [special_requirements] => no
    [party_size] => 2
    [reservation_code] => AWrRRPG6vUB6A6c6
)
1

Comment: @TiernO: All indications provided are suggesting that the query is executing successfully.  How specifically are you observing that it isn't?

Comment: @David My looking in PHPMyadmin and seeing that the row hasnt been updated

Comment: @David I restarted Apache and MySQL and sure enough it works now, i also changed the if statement to be just `if(response) {` so now its working great. Pretty weird and frustrating but now relieving

Comment: You are using `$data` in `editReservation` instead of `$reservation`